# Global variable not getting updated

Tags: python

I have a 10*22 matrix, which I am storing as a 2-D list of dots.

The initial matrix(left) has to be converted to the one on the right, the logic being that if a row has no dots, it has to be converted into one with all dots.

[image]
[image]

But for some reason, my matrix doesn't get updated when I call the function step. But when I print ***matrix*** , it gives me back the original unaltered one.

Below is my code:

```
WIDTH, HEIGHT =10, 22
matrix=[['.' for x in range(WIDTH)] for y in range(HEIGHT)]
'''
somewhere in between I am changing the matrix, and the result gets 
successfully stored in 'matrix'
'''

def step():
     global matrix                                                                                                                     
     for row in matrix:
         if row.count('.')==0:
             row = ['.' for elem in row]
```

Comment: do `row[:] = ['.' for elem in row]` if you must. or better: `row[:] = ['.'] * len(row)`

Comment: I see nowhere that you assign a new value to matrix. How to expect it changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem isn't the global variable but the `row` name being reassigned in the loop:

```
row = ['.' for elem in row]
```

that creates a *new* reference of `row`, unknown to `matrix`.

You could improve & fix by using *slice assignment* for instance & more efficient code:

```
 for row in matrix:
     if not '.' in row: # no need to count, just check if a dot is there
         row[:] = ['.'] * len(row)
```

this works but creates & copies a lot of data. A list comprehension instead of the loop would probably be better:

```
matrix = [row if '.' in row else ['.'] * len(row) for row in matrix]
```

(it works because `matrix` is global). Also `matrix` init could be simplified to:

```
matrix=[['.']*WIDTH for _ in range(HEIGHT)]
```

Since strings are immutable you can use multiplication to create the rows (but not for the outer loop!)

Comment: when I use the slice operator, am I not creating a new reference of row?